# Is there a way to delete a facebook pixel event?

Tags: facebook

I have added javascript to my page that tracks different events on buttons. I did some testing after I had launched a facebook campaign and the evnets I created got credited to one of the ads. Is it possble to delete specific events (purchase and InitialCheckout) that are registered by the pixel.